# Android Добавление массива JSONObject в JSONObject

Tags: android, json, post, put

Мне Нужно создать запрос JSON для отправки на сервер примерно такого формата:

```css
{
   "Names":"..."
   "Phone":"..."

  "appointments": [
    {
      "appointmentId": "app_001",
      "appointmentTitle": "Appointment Title1",
       "params":   "{ 
                        \"selectedAdditionals\":"...",
                        \"selectedOptionsMap\":"..."     
                     }",
    },
                  ]
}
```

Но я что-то делаю не так. У меня появляются слешы в массиве там, где не надо. Подскажите, как от них избавиться.

Вот код:

```
  JSONObject account = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray users = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject user = new JSONObject();
        mainObj = new JSONObject();

        JSONObject jsnarr = new JSONObject();
        jsnarr.put("hello","...");
        List <JSONObject> arr=new ArrayList<>();


        arr.add(jsnarr);
        JSONObject jsnob = new JSONObject();


        JSONObject jsnarred = new JSONObject();
        jsnarred.put("hello4","...");


        jsnob.put("hello2",jsnarred);
        jsnarr.put("jsnob", jsnob);

        account.put("users", arr);
        users.put("user");



        mainObj.put("account", arr);
```

Вот что получаю:

```css
{
    "account":
            "[  
               {
              \"hello\":\"...\",
              \"jsnob\":{
                          \"hello2\":   
                            {\"hello4\":\"...\"
                         }
                  }
                }
               ]"

}
```

Comment: Изменил последнюю строку в коде на:     mainObj.put ("account", new JSONArray (arr)); Слешы пропали, но они пропали и во внутреннем объекте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё получилось, всё заработало. Вот код:

```
     JSONObject account = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray users = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject user = new JSONObject();
        mainObj = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject jsnarr = new JSONObject();
        jsnarr.put  ("hello","...");
        List <JSONObject> arr=new ArrayList<>();
        JsonObject jsnob = new JsonObject();
        jsnob.addProperty("hello2","asdf");
        jsnarr.put("jsnob", jsnob);
        arr.add(jsnarr);
        account.put("users", arr);
        users.put("user");
        mainObj.put ("account", new JSONArray (arr));
```